# Using Python to write Javascript: look for indexOf new line

Tags: javascript, python

I'm using Python to write to a html file some  javascript code.

I'm trying to get the index position of the first occurrence of a new line after a string is found in the main text.

Example text:

```html
This is a line of text
A second line of text here
log writing has started
first line of log text
second line of log text
```

So I'm trying to get the index position of the f in 'first', as that is the first character after a new line once 'log writing has started' has been found

OUT is the html file I'm writing to

```js
OUT.write(' var log_string = document.getElementById("logtext").innerHTML;')
OUT.write(' var screen_index = log_string.indexOf("log writing has started");')
OUT.write(' var screen_log = log_string.indexOf("\r", screen_index);')
```

log_string = the big chunk of text

screen_index = the index of where that sentence begins

screen_log = the index of the next new line after 'screen_index'

The trouble I'm having is specifying the new line. Because I'm writing a python file that outputs a .html file, I think it's getting confused with the \r

The error I'm getting is:

```html
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I've tried

```js
OUT.write(' var screen_log = log_string.indexOf(r"\n", screen_index);')
```

(adding an r before the "\n")

But then I get the error

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping `\n`:

```
OUT.write(' var screen_log = log_string.indexOf("\\n", screen_index);')
```

In your code, when you write \n a new line is printed and the line is split in two.

Comment: That's it! So what's going on with the double \? I'm used to Python but I'm still pretty new to it, but Javascript is very new for me. Is a double \ in javascript a way to write code in a string a bit like r in python?

Comment: It has nothing to do with javascript. \\n would be like what you intended to do with r"\n". The problem is that you had r"\n" inside a string. Check `print('r"\n"')` (what you had) and `print(r"\n")`